# how to config session timeout separately for each service provider in WSO2 identity server?

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I'm using WSO2 Identity Server 5.1.0. i want control session timeout with configure session timeout for each service provider not only for all service providers over identity server.

exist any solution or idea that it can satisfied my problem?

Answer (score 1):

Service Provider's session should be managed by Service Provider itself. WSO2 Identity Server (or any other Identity Provider) doesn't have any control over Service Providers' sessions (and their timeouts). Each SP must handle their session timeouts and request the authentication from IdP.

Only thing WSO2 Identity Server have the control is the session user-agent (browser) has with Identity Server itself. In case you need to configure that, you can refer [this doc](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/Configuring+Session+Timeout). But as said above, it will be applicable to Identity Server Session only.